# Debug .Net/IIS crash which doesn't crash with debugger attached

Tags: asp.net, iis, crash, iis-7.5, debugdiag

I have a .Net web application which has started crashing in production and I'm not sure why. It's crashing very frequently (around every 5 minutes under high load) and takes the application pool down with it. In the event log I only have the following:

> Faulting application name: w3wp.exe, version: 7.5.7601.17514, time stamp: 0x4ce7afa2
>      Faulting module name: unknown, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x00000000
>      Exception code: 0x00000000
>      Fault offset: 0x000007fe97df95dc

The exception code of `0x00000000` is not particularly helpful.

Normally from here I would attempt to get a crash dump and take a look. However, whenever `DebugDiag` is running, the app does not crash. This makes it much harder to track down. Memory usage climbs heavily when DebugDiag is running (2gb every 6 hours?), but I presume that is normal.

Not really sure where to go from here.

Comment: I am having the same problem but with a different exception code.  We have 3 servers and they all throw the exception every 2-3 days.  If I attach DebugDiag to one of the servers, the exception stops being thrown.

Answer (score 1):

Exception code 0x00000000 is a bit weird. Not sure what can cause that (maybe a call to environment.failfast in some .net code probably)

Regarding memory consumption, please make sure you are using the latest debug diagnostic tool (version 2 update 2) and then in the preferences section for crash rules, you can adjust settings to avoid loggin exceptions which will ensure that all unhandled exceptions are not logged). Typically that is what consumes most of the memory. Also make sure that LeakTrack status is blank under processes tab for the process you are tracking.

Comment: This got me pretty close so worth the upvote. I think it was actually a call to `Debugger.Break()` which erroneously didn't have a conditional compile wrapper and went live.